# Package/@Languages in WiX 4

Tags: wix, wix4

In WiX 3 there is Package/@Languages element to specify a list of language the MSI package supports. When using wix convert tool to upgrade to WiX4, this element just gets removed. How do you specify languages in WiX 4 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSI package language can be set in either of the following ways:

1. Directly in the `Package/@Language` attribute.
2. Using a .wxl file with the `Localization/@Culture` attribute set.

During the build, the summary information will be set correctly. The Windows Installer does not officially support setting multiple languages on an MSI package, so the `Package/@Languages` attribute in WiX v3 was unnecessary and could create invalid packages with mismatched languages. That bug was fixed in WiX v4.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want the workaround, you can add this to your build system before you sign your package:

WiLangId.vsb script from the [Windows MSI SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/) with said syntax:

```
>> WiLangId.vsb [path to .msi] Package [List of language codes, comma separated]
```

This seems to mimic the behavior of what @Languages was doing, but keep in the mind there is another documented best practice way, although it seems a little more complicated and a harder transition if you're upgrading from Wix v3.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/manage-substorages

Also see this discussion:
https://github.com/orgs/wixtoolset/discussions/7325