# Wix MultiLingual installer: Default strings are in English even in Hindi Locale

Tags: windows-installer, wix3, wix4, heatwave

I had created a MultiLingual MSI. That means a single MSI when run in different locales shows the text based on the locale set on the system. MSI works fine for all languages but not for Hindi.
In WIX3 version:
Inside Product.wxs file I add languages codes (Hindi 1081) separated by comma in

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="$(var.MainApp)" Language="!(loc.Language)" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="Duo Security" UpgradeCode="2c72db34-bla-bla-vla">
    <Package InstallerVersion="500" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine"
             Languages="1033,1031,3082,1036,1041,1046,1045,1057,2052,1081" InstallPrivileges="elevated"/>
```

Then add hi-in.wxl file to the project to handle any custom string.

In WIX4:
Languages property was removed. So I use Wilangid.vbs to inject language codes in MSI.
[Package/@Languages in WiX 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75879120/package-languages-in-wix-4)

The same concept works for all languages but not Hindi.
Wix does support Hindi according to
https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oe376/6c085406-a698-4e12-9d4d-c3b0ee3dbc4a
https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/wixui/wixui_localization/

I have tried other languages it work fine but not for Hindi alone. Is Hindi in fact a supported language?